# Why is this "reality check" question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

From what I can see, this question

https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/can-a-person-copy-basketball-moves-as-fast-as-kise-ryota-in-kuroko-no-basket

is no different from these "reality check" questions:

- [Does the "running technique" of Seiho players exist in real life?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19670/does-the-running-technique-of-seiho-players-exist-in-real-life)
- [Can the skills shown in Kuroko no Basuke be achieved in real life?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/can-the-skills-shown-in-kuroko-no-basuke-be-achieved-in-real-life) <sup>1</sup>
- [How accurate is the cooking in Food Wars?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/how-accurate-is-the-cooking-in-food-wars)
- [How is Misaka's railgun so destructive?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/how-is-misakas-railgun-so-destructive)

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'd understand if the above question were closed as duplicate of this one</sup>

All of these questions require (citing) knowledge outside anime and manga to answer. How is it so different from the other "reality check" question that warrant its closure?

There is a [previous meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/is-it-ever-acceptable-to-ask-about-whether-an-anime-event-is-realistic-or-plausi) about this, where the only answer suggests that

> "If we can remove references to the anime and manga and still have a standalone, answerable question, then it is off-topic."

However, to a person who hasn't read the series, they can't tell what kind of basketball move is being copied here.

Answer (score 2):

**I closed the question because it does not appear to be about anime or manga.**

You do, however, have a point that the question is answered elsewhere and should instead have been closed as a duplicate of [this other question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/can-the-skills-shown-in-kuroko-no-basuke-be-achieved-in-real-life), so I have done just that.

As for the examples you posted in the question, all but the second one seem to be asked in a slightly different spirit *to me*.
The first and third are different from the question you're posting about because they ask about whether or not things that happen in the anime/manga are based/have references in real-world events/facts, or if they're just completely made up facts/concepts.
The fourth one *basically* asks about whether or not we can consider events that take place in the anime/manga as if they took place on our world (as in, according to our laws of physics), or if that all goes out the window and the discrepancy you may stumble upon if you look too closely (as in, do the math) is due to anime physics.

The second one, however, I'd argue that *could* be considered off-topic. However, this citation you posted

> "If we can remove references to the anime and manga and still have a standalone, answerable question, then it is off-topic."

does make some sense.

The question you're concerned about, however, doesn't strike me as so much about the anime/manga as that example. I read it more as a "Is it possible for me to do this thing I saw in an anime in real life?"
The question had two close votes when I closed it, both of which for "Primarily opinion-based" — maybe I should have gone with that instead, it was valid. Either way, the user (or someone else, for that matter) could have reworded the question in such a way that it fit better into the scope of our site.