# Is this spam or an extremely naive question? Should questions like those be answered?

Tags: discussion

[Can I do a Tiger Shoot like Hyuga Kojiro from anime Captain Tsubasa](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/50621/can-i-do-a-tiger-shoot-like-hyuga-kojiro-from-anime-captain-tsubasa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these type of questions I would suggest we assume good faith as opposed to malicious intent.

Up to this day, certain people still assume they can, by the means of training, obtain the ability to use a Kamehameha. So why couldn't they wonder about a kick that can break waves?

Answering as you did, saying they can't, and possibly explaining why makes for a good answer to these questions. And if you feel that the question lacks research effort, feel free to down vote it. This is what down votes is meant for after all.

Comment: I would actually point [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/668/49) for a bit more nuance on the answer — as it stands, for instance, the question is not about anime at all, but much more about real world physics or something of the sort, which would make it off-topic.